# Spring Security + Angular 7 | LDAP Authentication

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, ldap

I have a **big problem**. I'm sitting here now for a few days thinking about how to get my **login app** working. I want it to send the **username and password to spring boot** where it gets checked. The basic stuff in Spring boot is already working (loginForm). I'm pretty new in **programming with Spring Boot** because i did NodeJS before. The goal is to verify users over LDAP in the Backend but with Spring Security not with Pure **Java (would be easy tho)**. That whole thing of course witch **HTTP Requests** (Endpoints)

Here is what i have till now:

```
// WebSecurityConfiguration

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/test").permitAll()
            .usernameParameter("_username_")
            .passwordParameter("_password_")
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
            .ldapAuthentication()
            .userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people")
            .groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
            .contextSource()
            .url("ldap://localhost:8389/dc=springframework,dc=org")
            .and()
            .passwordCompare()
            .passwordEncoder(new LdapShaPasswordEncoder())
            .passwordAttribute("userPassword");

}

@Bean
public DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource() {
    return new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(Arrays.asList("ldap://localhost:8389/"), "dc=springframework,cd=org");
}
```

I'm using Gradle because we are using it in our company as default so here's the **build.gradle**:

```
// build.gradle

    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


group = 'net.company'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-ldap'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    runtimeOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    compile("org.springframework.ldap:spring-ldap-core")
    compile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-ldap")
    compile("org.springframework:spring-tx")
    compile("com.unboundid:unboundid-ldapsdk")
    compile group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.2.4'
    compile group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-core', version: '2.3.0.1'
    compile group: 'javax.xml', name: 'jaxb-impl', version: '2.1'
    compile group: 'javax.activation', name: 'activation', version: '1.1.1'
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testCompile("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}
```

And that's my **app.component.ts** for now. I already imported the HttpClientModule and added it to the **imports**:

```
// app.component.ts

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';

import * as Stomp from 'stompjs';
import * as SockJS from 'sockjs-client';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Memory';
  status: string;

  greeting = {};

  private serverUrl = 'http://localhost:8082/';
  private stompClient;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.initializeWebSocketConnection();
    http.get(this.serverUrl + 'login').subscribe(data => data);
  }

  initializeWebSocketConnection() {
    let ws = new SockJS(this.serverUrl);
    this.stompClient = Stomp.over(ws);
    let that = this;
    this.stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
      that.stompClient.subscribe('/chat', (message) => {
        console.log(message);
      });
    });
  }

  sendMessage(msg) {
    this.stompClient.send('/app/send/message', {}, msg);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setStatus('login');
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.sendMessage('test =>');
    }, 5000);
  }

  setStatus(status): void {
    this.status = status;
  }
}
```

[Login App Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/stn89.png)

```
// login.component.html

    <div id="container"
     fxLayout="column"
     fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  <div class="spacer" fxFlex="10%"></div>
  <div id="login" fxFlex="25%"
       fxLayout="column"
       fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <h1 id="loginTitle" fxFlex="35%">LOGIN</h1>
    <label for="user"></label><input id="user" placeholder="username" fxFlex="17.5%" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('loginButton').click()"/>
    <div class="spacer" fxFlex="10%"></div>
    <label for="password"></label><input type="password" id="password" placeholder="password" fxFlex="17.5%" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('loginButton').click()"/>
    <div class="spacer" fxFlex="10%"></div>
    <img id="loginButton" src="../../assets/login/img/right-arrow.png" fxFlex="10%" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="spacer" fxFlex="74%"></div>
  <div id="attention" fxFlex="1%">Icons made by <a href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/lyolya" title="Lyolya">Lyolya</a></div>
</div>
```

Here the **application.properties** for those guys who need informations about the **LDAP** stuff (**application.yml** is **empty** for now):

```
// application.properties

spring.ldap.embedded.ldif=classpath:test-server.ldif
spring.ldap.embedded.base-dn=dc=springframework,dc=org
spring.ldap.embedded.port=8389
server.servlet.context-path=/
server.port=8082
```

If you need more informations or files pls just PM me. 
**I will refactor this article if we get a solution so its easy to understand for all beginners.**

Comment: Are there not plenty of tutorials online? Depending on your approach, the configurations changes (eg. are you using jwt)

Comment: @Prashant No im not using jwt. there are only a few tutorials online for that. And they all said something else. But as I already said im beginner in this section. So if you know one it would be nice if you pm me the link. I added the application.properties to the post. application.yml is empty.

Comment: @Prashant One guy out of our office just said I should use jwt so im having a look at it now.

Comment: the rest of the world would be happy if you use jwt.

Comment: Please add any error messages you have or what exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Sim_on I have my Frontend (Angular). And from there I wanna send username and password to spring boot. And in Spring Boot I want to check it then and send it back. That whole thing with LDAP

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to add custom filter implementation. I would recommend going over [Spring Security Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/), check out point 9.

So ideally, since you do it over HTTP&REST, you would need any JWT library to transfer tokens over to Angular and verifying them in your Spring backend.

You should override `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`  and add your implementations of `attemptAuthentication` and `successfulAuthentication` methods.

In first you would need to check whether posted username and passwords are correct, for example:

```
 try {
      LoginDto loginDto = new ObjectMapper().readValue(request.getInputStream(), LoginDto.class);
      if (getAuthenticationManager() == null) logger.warn("Authentication manager is null!");
      return getAuthenticationManager()
          .authenticate(
              new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                  loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword(), new ArrayList<>()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
      logger.warn(e.getMessage());
    }
    throw new AuthenticationServiceException("Credentials are invalid");
```

In the second you issue your token to your Angular client so that user could provide it later to your backend/s, e.g.:

```
 String userName = authResult.getName();
    try {
      User user = userService.findUserByUserName(userName);

      if (user.getAccountLocked()
          .getLockDate()
          .before(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now().minus(15, ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))) {
        throw new UserLockedException();
      }

      List<String> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
      user.getAuthorities().forEach(e -> authorities.add(e.getAuthority()));
      Map<String, Object> claims = new LinkedHashMap<>();
      claims.put("email", user.getEmail());
      claims.put("firstName", user.getFirstName());
      claims.put("lastName", user.getLastName());
      claims.put("authorities", authorities);
      String token =
          Jwts.builder()
              .setSubject(user.getId())
              .addClaims(claims)
              .setExpiration(
                  new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + Long.parseLong(jwtConfig.getExpiration())))
              .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, jwtConfig.getSecret())
              .compact();
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.setHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

      userService.successfulLogin(user);
      userService.resetLoginAttempts(user);

    } catch (NotFoundException e) {
      logger.warn(e.getMessage());
    }
  }
```

Add this filter to your http configuration:

```
        Collections.singletonList(daoAuthenticationProvider()));
    AuthenticationFilter filter =  new AuthenticationFilter(userService,manager, mapper, jwtConfig);
    filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/login");

    http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
        .and().addFilter(filter);
```